# Getting the number of posts that a user has posted?

Tags: mysql

How can I get the number of posts that a user has posted using one MySQL query?

I can't really think of anything but this, but there is no aggregate function on the join.  So I'm not sure how to proceed.  I am positive that `joins` will not accomplish what I need.

```
select a1.username as Username
from `logs` as a1
left join `logs` as a2
on a1.username = a2.username
```

For example, my `logs` table is filled with information about posts people have made.  I want to find how many posts each user has made, i.e.

```
Username, Posts
User1     100
User2     200
```

etc

EDIT: Sorry for not providing enough information.

I have a table called `logs` and it has two columns.  One column is called `username` and another column is called `msg`.  It basically holds information about posts that people have posted.

For example, let's say someone named `Red` posts `Hello world`.  It will be saved to the table `logs` and a new row will be created.  `username` will be `Red`, and `msg` will be `Hello world`

I basically want to get the number of messages that EVERY SINGLE user has posted by their username.  I.e. here is an example of what I want

```
Username Posts
Red 1
Blue 10
Sally 30
```

Comment: r u trying to join `users` and `logs`?

Comment: an sqlfiddle would be good

Comment: How about GROUP BY and SUM?

Comment: On second thought, why are you joining `logs` to `logs`?

Comment: Yes.  I am joining logs to logs because I somehow want to get the number of posts the user posted.  For example, the first query gets their username, and the join gets the number of posts they have made.  But I can't use functions inside that join such as COUNT(*)

Comment: Is it a requirement or is it simply not working? Because if the latter, then would need to have aggregate data to use aggregate functions, i.e., you need to GROUP BY.

Comment: Try `select a1.username as Username, Count(1) as Posts
from logs as a1
group by a1.Username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you say you "can't use count(*) in a join", you mean that you tried and saw that it didn't work, rather than you can't use COUNT at all. So I'm using it here.

You're right that a JOIN is the wrong place for a COUNT. You want it up in the SELECT column list, and a GROUP BY down below. Aggregate by Username, and count the number of entries in each aggregate.

```
SELECT Username, COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM logs
GROUP BY Username
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT Username, count(Posts) 
FROM `logs`
GROUP BY Username;
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This query may help you, change this query as for your requirement

```
SELECT users.*, count( posts.user_id ) 
FROM posts LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=posts.user_id 
GROUP BY posts.user_id
```

may be like

```
SELECT users.username, count( logs.username ) as posts 
FROM users LEFT JOIN logs ON users.username=posts.username 
GROUP BY users.username
```